# Error:Lambda coming from jar file need their interfaces on the classpath to be compiled, unknown interfaces are java.util.function.Function

Tags: android, gradle, lambda, java-8

I am writing android project. Some of the external libraries requires the use of Java8. However, when I add Java8 using Jack, the project isn't recognizing the components of Java8. What might be the problem?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.infiniteloop.android.translateyandex"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}
dexOptions {
    incremental true
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}


buildscript {
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {

 }
}


 configurations.all {
   resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'
 }
repositories {
  maven {
     url "https://jitpack.io"
  }
}
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
    core:2.2.2', {
       exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.vbauer:yandex-translate-api:1.2.5'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  }
```

And here is the error list
[Errorlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwU5C.png)

Comment: the solution I provided worked for you?

Comment: I am trying it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) gradle plugin for getting java lambda support in java 6, 7 and android

Just add: `apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'`
line in your app level build.gradle file below the line: `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

Now in your project level build.gradle add :

```
classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.6.0'
```

in your dependencies section

EG:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.6.0'
}
```

And sync it :)

Answer (score 1):

You use

`multiDexEnabled true`

Add above link to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

OR

```
MultiDex.install(this);
```

in your custom Application's attachBaseContext method

or your custom Application extend MultiDexApplication

and add above

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Hope it help.