# Using Java 8 in Android Studio 2.3.2 does not work

Tags: java, android

I have an APi that was built for Java 8.
Currently, I have Android Studio 2.3.2 on Ubuntu and to be honest, I hesitate to update it.

I used Jack and set target and source compatibility to Java Version 1.8.
When I am in debug modus, everything works as expected.

But when I want to create a signed apk I get errors like these:

[Error:Lambda coming from jar file need their interfaces on the classpath to be compiled, unknown interfaces are java.util.function.Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320838/errorlambda-coming-from-jar-file-need-their-interfaces-on-the-classpath-to-be-c)

I tried this one here https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda

But checking the java version with "java --version" tells me that I have Java 1.8 already installed on my machine.

What can I do? I don't want to update to Android 3+
This is my gradle (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.project.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 12
    versionName "1.055"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled = true
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }

}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", GoogleMapDebug
    }

    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", GoogleMapRelease


    }


    compileOptions{
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }




}

sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/asset/'] } }
 }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.+'
compile 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
compile 'com.patrickpissurno:ripple-effect:1.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.5.2'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:3.3.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
compile 'com.github.medyo:android-about-page:1.2.5'
compile 'de.codengine:tankerkoenig-api-client:1.0'


testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 }
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is the gradle (project):

```
  // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("gradle.properties")
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
```

Comment: supporting java-8 starts from android studio 3.0+ I think you need to update your android studio now check  this https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

Comment: @MoustafEL-Saghier what about this : https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda

Comment: can u check deprecated section and integration to the android studio? I prefer to work it directly using android studio without any workaround.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: you have to update android studio and use it officially

Comment: @MoustafEL-Saghier the problem is that an update ALWAYS cause gradle problems. And I don't want to mess up my project.

Comment: why not backup your projects and reinstall the whole program?